# How can data from a json query be declared as a variable so it can be used in calculations?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to simply multiply column 3 times the HIVEPrice (labeled as const HIVEusd). The data desired is retrieved in the json query and displays, but I am having trouble declaring a variable that I can use in the const valusd = res * HIVEusd line (246). Everything is working, except that the 2 in line 245 should be the HIVEusd result from the json (the 2 was just for testing things). Thanks for any help. :)

[image: front end on the left, code on the right]

```js
<script language=javascript>
const toFix = str => (+str).toFixed(6); // perhaps should do 6 to show more precision?
const calc = $div => {
  const $row = $div.closest("tr")
  const $cells = $row.find("td");
  const qty = +$cells.eq(2).text().split(" ")[0];
  const val = $div.text()
  // console.log($div.attr("id"),val, qty, val * qty)
  const res = val * qty
  $cells.eq(3).text(isNaN(res) ? "" : res.toFixed(4)); // or (2) but then several will show 0.00
  // figure the USD value below res (HIVE value) times HIVEusd equals token USD value
  const HIVEusd = 2
  const valusd = res * HIVEusd
  $cells.eq(4).text(isNaN(valusd) ? "" : valusd.toFixed(4)); // or (4) for more precision in decimals

};
// Fetch HIVE price in USD
$.getJSON("https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/price?fsym=HIVE&tsyms=USD", function(data) {
  $("#HIVEPrice").text(toFix(data["USD"]));
  calc($("#HIVEPrice"));
}).fail(function(dat, textStatus, error) {
  var err = textStatus + ", " + error;
  alert(err);
});
// End HIVE price fetch


// Fetch Hive Engine token prices
$.getJSON("https://accounts.hive-engine.com/marketHistory?symbol=ALIVE", function(data) {
  $("#ALIVEPrice").text(toFix(data[0].closePrice));
  calc($("#ALIVEPrice"));
}).fail(function(dat, textStatus, error) {
  var err = textStatus + ", " + error;
  alert(err);
});

var CurrentPrice = document.getElementById('ALIVEPrice');
CurrentPrice.innerHTML = ALIVEPrice.innerHTML;

$.getJSON("https://accounts.hive-engine.com/marketHistory?symbol=BBH", function(data) {
  $("#BBHPrice").text(toFix(data[0].closePrice));
  calc($("#BBHPrice"));
}).fail(function(dat, textStatus, error) {
  var err = textStatus + ", " + error;
  alert(err);
});



$.getJSON("https://accounts.hive-engine.com/marketHistory?symbol=BEER", function(data) {
  $("#BEERPrice").text(toFix(data[0].closePrice));
  calc($("#BEERPrice"));
}).fail(function(dat, textStatus, error) {
  var err = textStatus + ", " + error;
  alert(err);
});



$.getJSON("https://accounts.hive-engine.com/marketHistory?symbol=ENGAGE", function(data) {
  $("#ENGAGEPrice").text(toFix(data[0].closePrice));
  calc($("#ENGAGEPrice"));
}).fail(function(dat, textStatus, error) {
  var err = textStatus + ", " + error;
  alert(err);
});



$.getJSON("https://accounts.hive-engine.com/marketHistory?symbol=LUV", function(data) {
  $("#LUVPrice").text(toFix(data[0].closePrice));
  calc($("#LUVPrice"));
}).fail(function(dat, textStatus, error) {
  var err = textStatus + ", " + error;
  alert(err);
});



$.getJSON("https://accounts.hive-engine.com/marketHistory?symbol=PIZZA", function(data) {
  $("#PIZZAPrice").text(toFix(data[0].closePrice));
  calc($("#PIZZAPrice"));
}).fail(function(dat, textStatus, error) {
  var err = textStatus + ", " + error;
  alert(err);
});



$.getJSON("https://accounts.hive-engine.com/marketHistory?symbol=WINEX", function(data) {
  $("#WINEXPrice").text(toFix(data[0].closePrice));
  calc($("#WINEXPrice"));
}).fail(function(dat, textStatus, error) {
  var err = textStatus + ", " + error;
  alert(err);
});

<!-- End Hive Engine token price and conversion engine -->



<!-- HE tip token calculations-->
function ALIVEconvert() {
  with(document.hivetiptokensform) {
    ALIVEConvert.value = (ALIVEtoken.value * CurrentPrice.innerHTML);
  }
}

function LiveConvert() {
  with(document.hivetiptokensform) {
    LiveConvert.value = (CurrentPrice.innerHTML);
  }
}

function USDConvert() {
  with(document.hivetiptokensform) {
    LiveConvert.value = (HEtoken.value * CurrentPrice.innerHTML * USDCurrentPrice.innerHTML);
  }
}

function hivevalueonehetoken() {
  with(document.hivetiptokensform) {
    hivevalueonehetoken.value = (CurrentPrice.innerHTML);
  }
}

function usdvalueonehetoken() {
  with(document.hivetiptokensform) {
    usdvalueonehetoken.value = (CurrentPrice.innerHTML * USDCurrentPrice.innerHTML);
  }
}

// End HE Tip Token calculations
</script>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Hive Tip Tokens Current Value</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">

  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <style>
  body {
    background: #fefefe;
    max-width: 750px;
    margin: 40px auto;
    padding: 0 22px;
    font: 18px/1.5 -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, /* MacOS and iOS */
    'avenir next', avenir, /* MacOS and iOS */
    'Segoe UI', /* Windows */
    'lucida grande', /* Older MacOS */
    'helvetica neue', helvetica, /* Older MacOS */
    'Fira Sans', /* Firefox OS */
    roboto, noto, /* Google stuff */
    'Droid Sans', /* Old Google stuff */
    cantarell, oxygen, ubuntu, /* Linux stuff */
    'franklin gothic medium', 'century gothic', /* Windows stuff */
    'Liberation Sans', /* Linux */
    sans-serif;
    /* Everything else */
    ;
    color: #222;
  }
  
  html {
    font-size: medium;
  }
  
  body {
    background-color: #f6f6f6;
    color: #330;
    font-family: verdana, georgia, times, serif;
    margin: ;
    max-width: 80em;
    padding: 0 1em;
    width: auto;
    font-size: 1rem;
    line-height: 1.4;
  }
  
  a {
    color: #1e6b8c;
    font-size: 1em;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition-delay: 0.1s;
    transition-duration: 0.3s;
    transition-property: color, background-color;
    transition-timing-function: linear;
  }
  
  a:visited {
    color: #6f32ad;
    font-size: 1em;
  }
  
  a:hover {
    background: #b6cff9;
    font-size: 1em;
    text-decoration: underline;
  }
  
  a:active {
    background-color: #427fed;
    color: #fffff6;
    color: white;
    font-size: 1em;
  }
  
  h1,
  h2,
  h3,
  h4,
  h5,
  h6 {
    color: #black;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 1.2;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
    margin-top: 2em;
  }
  
  h1 {
    font-size: 2.2em;
    text-align: center;
  }
  
  h2 {
    font-size: 1.8em;
    border-bottom: solid 0.1rem #703820;
  }
  
  h3 {
    font-size: 1.5em;
  }
  
  h4 {
    font-size: 1.3em;
    text-decoration: underline;
  }
  
  h5 {
    font-size: 1.2em;
    font-style: italic;
  }
  
  h6 {
    font-size: 1.1em;
    margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
  }
  
  pre,
  code,
  xmp {
    font-family: courier;
    font-size: 1rem;
    line-height: 1.4;
    white-space: pre-wrap;
  }
  
  input[type=number] {
    width: 135px;
  }
  </style>

</head>

<body>
  <a name="home_title"></a>
  <h1 id="H-E-tip-tokens"><strong>Hive-Engine </strong><span style="color: rgb(231, 2, 2)">tip tokens</span></h1>

  <p style="text-align:center">When you share or tip on H-E, here's how much the tip is worth:</p>

  <center>
    <form name="hivetiptokensform">
      <table id="calcTable">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Token</th>
            <th>Value of 1 in HIVE</th>
            <th>Tip amount</th>
            <th>Tip value in HIVE</th>
            <th>Tip value in USD</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>ALIVE</td>
            <td>
              <div id="ALIVEPrice">Loading last traded price...</div>
            </td>
            <td>0.1 ALIVE</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>BBH</td>
            <td>
              <div id="BBHPrice">Loading last traded price...</div>
            </td>
            <td>1 BBH</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>BEER</td>
            <td>
              <div id="BEERPrice">Loading last traded price...</div>
            </td>
            <td>0.1 BEER</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>ENGAGE</td>
            <td>
              <div id="ENGAGEPrice">Loading last traded price...</div>
            </td>
            <td>10 ENGAGE*</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>LUV</td>
            <td>
              <div id="LUVPrice">Loading last traded price...</div>
            </td>
            <td>1 LUV</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>PIZZA</td>
            <td>
              <div id="PIZZAPrice">Loading last traded price...</div>
            </td>
            <td>0.1 PIZZA</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>WINEX</td>
            <td>
              <div id="WINEXPrice">Loading last traded price...</div>
            </td>
            <td>0.1 WINEX</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </form>

  </center>

  <center><small><small>*ENGAGE may not have a standard tip quantity, as far as I can tell. Instead, a quantity must be set by the tipper. From what I've seen, 10 ENGAGE is a normally tipped amount.</small></small></center>

  <p>
    <center>
      <div id="HIVEPrice">Loading last traded price in USD...</div>
      <span style="color:firebrick">value of 1 HIVE in USD</span>
      <p>
    </center>
    <p>




      <p>
        <a href="javascript:document.location.reload();" ONMOUSEOVER="window.status='Refresh'; return true" ONMOUSEOUT="window.status='ahh...success'">
          <center><img src="images/refresh.png" width="85" height="" border="0" /></a>
        </center>
        <p>

      <p>
        <center>
          <small>
            All the prices are based off of the <b>last</b> trade made. These can vary wildly due to <b>one wild trade</b>. Always be careful and check Hive-Engine token markets for a wider view. <a href="https://hive-engine.com" target="_blank">Hive-Engine</a> | <a href="https://tribaldex.com" target="_blank">Tribal</a> | <a href="https://leodex.io" target="_blank">Leo</a>
          </small>
        </center>
      <p>
            <center><small>Made with <a href="https://peakd.com/@luvshares/about" target="_blank"><img src="images/LUV.png" border="0" width="38"></a> by <a href="https://peakd.com/@crrdlx/about" target="_blank">crrdlx</a></small></center>


            <!-- Default Statcounter code -->

            <!-- End of Statcounter Code -->
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: "I'm trying to simply multiply column 3 times the HIVEPrice (labeled as const HIVEusd). " This is not really a clear way to start a question imo. There are many columns you could be referring to, and the question doesn't specify enough context for me to determine the overall purpose of the Q. The picture is very confusing as well.

Comment: You're probably looking for `Promise.all` or `jQuery.when`

Comment: In response to the first comment...I'm trying to multiply column 3 times the HIVEusd value and display it in column 4. Currently, column 4 simply doubles column 3. I need to replace the "2" with the HIVEusd value. This is where I'm stuck.